# Excel VBA Wrong copy with Advanced Filter

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to get a list of unique data through the Advanced Filter option in Excel.
So, I recorded the macro I wanted to do and I got this as the code:

```
Sheets("Totaal").Range("A3:A65000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "D2"), Unique:=True
```

This should be fine as far as I know because I did this a few times. Problem is, with this one, he only copies the first element to the selected Range. (I tried with actually giving it a range but that didn't change anything).

So, only copying first element not the whole array. If I do it manually it works.

Comment: No I can't. There's data in there I can't share (work related). I guess you can't see anything wrong with the foruma as well? I let the people I'm making this for do it manually for now so it's not a pressing matter.

Comment: Have you tried doing the filter and copy in 2 steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled onto this one, very interesting problem. I created a test sheet to mimic yours that looked like:

[image: start]

The following code dropped all of the unique entries into col D starting at row 2:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim TotaalSheet As Worksheet

'set worksheet for easy reference
Set TotaalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Totaal")

'apply the advanced filter to get uniques
With TotaalSheet.Range("A3:A65000")
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=TotaalSheet.Range("D2"), Unique:=True
End With

End Sub
```

Here are the results:

[image: end]

Comment: I found that if the first one or more cells in the range you are working on, e.g., TotaalSheet.Range("A3:A65000"), is Blank, then the copy fails or stops.

Comment: Hey @Alan, could you elaborate on that? I certainly don't want incorrect code floating around haha. Does it fail if the data is not continuous?

Answer (score 0):

nothing is copied if the one of many empty cells on top of the range.